# Installing modules automatically with egg link

Tags: python, pycharm, package, pyodbc

I have my personal utils package `zhou_utils` that I create an egg link to with the following -
`pip install -e C:\Users\CZhou2\PycharmProjects\zhou_utils\`

I recently added a new file that uses `pyodbc` and installed it in `zhou_utils`. The methods work successfully from there.

However, when I try to run my utils methods now from my other projects, I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyodbc'`.

I went back and changed my setup to show that `pyodbc` is a required install, and it's reflected under the egg info.

Do I need to install `pyodbc` myself in every project that uses `zhou_utils`? I thought this would occur automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If your `setup.py` file indicates that `pyodbc` is a dependency, you have to re-install (*upgrade*) your package `zhou_utils`.

```
pip install --upgrade -e C:\Users\CZhou2\PycharmProjects\zhou_utils\
```